# Node app cannot connect to remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js

Node app is on SERVER1, MySQL is on SERVER2

Node app connection code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "REMOTE_IP",
  port: "3306",
  database: "REMOTE_DATABASE",
  user: "REMOTE_USER",
  password: "PASSWORD"
});


con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
        console.log("MySQL connection error: " + err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log("Connected to MySQL...");
```

Error message:

```
MySQL connection error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED REMOTE_IP:3306
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/process/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/home/process/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
at Connection.connect (/home/process/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/process/process.js:27:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

MySQL is running on port 3306 on SERVER2:

```
$ sudo netstat -plunt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4893/mysqld
```

Port 3306 is allowed by UFW on SERVER2:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The MySQL user has remote access rights on SERVER2:

```
mysql> SELECT * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'REMOTE_USER'%";
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE                     | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| 'REMOTE_USER'@'localhost'     | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
| 'REMOTE_USER'@'SERVER1_PUBLIC_IP' | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
| 'REMOTE_USER'@'SERVER1_PRIVATE_IP'  | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Connecting to MySQL via the command line on SERVER2 works fine:

```
$ mysql -u REMOTE_USER -pPASSWORD REMOTE_DATABASE
```

There is nothing in the MySQL or UFW logs.

I'm not sure what else to check...

Can you think of anything which could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: How about trying to connect from server1 to server2 via command line?

Comment: @AyushGupta Thanks for your reply. I have no `bindip` set in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is only listening on local connections. Notice in your netstat command:

```
127.0.0.1:3306
```

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address) for binding to 0.0.0.0. Basically, you just want to make sure `bind-address` is commented out in your `my.cnf` file, and it should start listening on all interfaces.

Comment: Ah! I was looking for bind-address in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but actually it's in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. Commenting it out didn't solve the problem, but setting it to `0.0.0.0` did. Thanks for your help!